# Ionic 5 - Set Today is MIN Day

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5.
I am trying to make **today is my `[min]` date.**

So users can select **today and days after today**.

my code is

```
 minDate: any = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getDate() - 0)).toISOString();


 <ion-datetime class="ion-no-padding top-padding" display-timezone="utc" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [min]='minDate'>
 </ion-datetime>
```

Ex= Today is 18 Jun 2021

so users can select the same and *after the date* of 18 Jun 2021.

> = 18 Jun 2021
>
> = 19 Jun 2021
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> any date after 18 Jun 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for this purpose :

Please install moment library for use anykind of datetime format :

```
npm install moment --save
```

and in your .ts file put this :

```
MinDate :any;

this.MinDate = moment('18/06/2021', "YYYY-MM-DD").add('days', 1).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

and in Todate of HTML code put inside `<ion-datetime>` tag

```
  <ion-datetime formControlName="ToDate" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
                    [min]=MinDate
                      required></ion-datetime>
```

output :

it will Open Datepicker from 19/06/2021
it won't let you select date 18/06/2021 and before this dates.

Comment: I need a dynamic day not static 18/06/2021. Thanks !!!

Comment: Please pass obj in place of  '18/06/2021'

Comment: Kya Pritesh object pass kiya to hua dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datetime-22uyca?file=components/date-picker/date-picker.ts) you can use like this

```
<ion-datetime class="ion-no-padding top-padding" display-timezone="utc" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" min="{{minDate}}"max="2100-12-31" ></ion-datetime>
```

in component

```
 minDate: any = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: First Thanks! But in this and I get 2021, `not 2022, 2023 . . . n`.  I need  ` 2021, 2022, 2023  to n` with DD and MM.

Comment: @Pritesh adding max attribute u can do it like max="2100-12-31"

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are UTC so you may face the min value that you don't expect (depends on your current system timezone)

Comment: I had the same problem with the year and set a max date to make things work.